# variable variables in parameter

Tags: php, variables, random

I want to bind a variable amount of results from a database.

```
$randomAmount = rand(0, 10);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $randomAmount; $i++) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($databaseGet, ${'op'. $i});
}
```

It runs the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` function a random amount of times. What I want to achieve is the $randomAmount as variable in the parameter.

So, if $randomAmount = 4, the code should do something to achieve this:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($databaseGet, $op1, $op2, $op3, $op4;
```

Comment: As per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), mysqli_stmt_bind_result binds variables to columns so it's not clear how it could be a variable number of columns.

Comment: I want to reuse this function. the query with amount of columns comes in as a variable. Something like this:

$query = "select k1, k2, k3, k4 FROM table"
$randomAmount = 4;

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`call_user_func_array` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) as follow:

```
$vars = [$databaseGet]
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $vars[] = &${'op' . $i};
}

call-user-func-array('mysqli_stmt_bind_result', $vars);
```